# Remove all text that do not start with (EC using sed awk grep

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this and I want to have only EC numbers from file.

```
5'-nucleotidase SurE (EC 3.1.3.5)
L-aspartate oxidase (EC 1.4.3.16)
Nicotinamide-nucleotide adenylyltransferase, NadM family (EC 2.7.7.1) @ Nicotinate-nucleotide adenylyltransferase, NadM family (EC 2.7.7.18)
Nicotinamidase (EC 3.5.1.19)
Quinolinate phosphoribosyltransferase [decarboxylating] 
NAD synthetase (EC 6.3.1.5) / Glutamine amidotransferase chain of NAD synthetase
4'-phosphopantetheinyl transferase (EC 2.7.8.-)
```

The output should be like:

```
(EC 3.1.3.5)
(EC 1.4.3.16)
(EC 2.7.7.1)
(EC 2.7.7.18)
(EC 3.5.1.19)    
(EC 6.3.1.5)    
(EC 2.7.8.-)
```

Comment: What does the input file look like?

Comment: please add code you tried.. do you need multiple matches to be output in same line and empty line if no match?

Answer (score 1):

Simply with **`grep`**:

```
grep -o '(EC [^)]*)' file
```

- `[^)]*` - match all characters except closing bracket `)`

The output:

```
(EC 3.1.3.5)
(EC 1.4.3.16)
(EC 2.7.7.1)
(EC 2.7.7.18)
(EC 3.5.1.19)
(EC 6.3.1.5)
(EC 2.7.8.-)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -n 's/^\(.*\)\((EC[^)]*)\).*$/\2/p'
```

and the `awk` fun version:

```
awk -F'\\(EC|\\)' 'NF==3 { print "(EC" $2 ")" }'
```